# SELECT one from multiple rows based on variable

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

Guys would you have any idea how to solve that problem?

I've hit a brick wall.  I'm writing a code behind a report.  Report has to show  `Colour` based on the `FinancialYear` variable.

Here is a table example:

[image: Table]

```
CompanyID |   StartDate |    EndDate   | ReviewDate   | FinancialYear | Colour
      46  |  2012-01-18 |  2013-12-17  |  2013-12-15  |  2012         | Red
      46  |  2013-12-17 |  1900-01-01  |  2017-03-10  |  2014         | Red 
      46  |  2011-05-11 |  2012-01-17  |  2011-06-30  |  2014         | Orange
```

When variable `FinancialYear` would be `2016`, `CompanyID` should show `Colour Red` as `EndDate` is `''`
result should show row nnumber `2`.

However, if `FinancialYear` variable would be `2012` I have two rows which would fit the criteria and would need to select the one that greater `EndDate` or `StartDate`, `Reviewdate`. 
The result should show row number 1.

Would anyone has an idea how to do it?  Thanks for any feedback!

What I've tried so far:

```
SELECT 
    CompanyID
,   StartDate AS [Traffic Lights Start Date]
,   EndDate AS [Traffic Lights End Date]
,   ReviewDate AS [Traffic Lights Review Date]
,   Category AS [Traffic Lights Colour] 
,   CASE 
        WHEN    (YEAR(EndDate) <> 1900 
            AND @FinancialYear BETWEEN (YEAR(DATEADD(DD,0, DATEDIFF(DD,0,     DATEADD(MM, -(((12 + DATEPART(M, CAST(StartDate AS DATETIME))) - 7)%12),     CAST(StartDate AS DATETIME))))) +1)
                             AND (YEAR(DATEADD(DD,0, DATEDIFF(DD,0, DATEADD(MM, -(((12 + DATEPART(M, CAST(EndDate AS DATETIME))) - 7)%12), CAST(EndDate AS DATETIME))))) +1)  
        AND (YEAR(DATEADD(DD,0, DATEDIFF(DD,0, DATEADD(MM, -(((12 + DATEPART(M, CAST(ReviewDate AS DATETIME))) - 7)%12), CAST(ReviewDate AS DATETIME)))))+1) >= @FinancialYear)
            THEN '1'
            WHEN 
                (YEAR(EndDate) = 1900 
            AND YEAR(ReviewDate) > = @FinancialYear)
            THEN '1' 
        ELSE '0'
    END AS FinancialYear_TrafficLights
,   (YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-((DATEPART(MONTH,CAST(StartDate AS DATETIME)) +7) %12),CAST(StartDate AS DATETIME)))+1) AS Actual_Financial_Year
,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY StartDate ASC) AS LatestRow
FROM 
    CompanyTrafficLightHistory
```

Comment: please add your table definition using show create table.

Comment: Show what you've tried? Even if it's not working, it shows effort & your train of thought

Comment: Thanks! :) Not sure how to add the code with SQL formatting here but I've edited my Questions with it.

Comment: I think I have to order output in some way and then just pick top 1 from it...but I'm not sure if what I'm thinking is right nor, how to achieve it with

Comment: What is your desired output?  Please add a table with what you want the results of your script to be.

Comment: Sorry for late response, Dave and big thanks for the Answer!  I got stuck on trying to figure it out for at least a day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only after the one row then you are right in that you need to order your dataset and then `select top 1`.  You can change the way the dataset is ordered in the `order by` clause by adding or removing fields and using `desc` to specify a descending order (the default is ascending):

```
declare @t table (CompanyID int
                    ,StartDate date
                    ,EndDate date
                    ,ReviewDate date
                    ,FinancialYear int
                    ,Colour nvarchar(50)
                    );
insert into @t values
 (46,'20120118','20131217','20131215',2012,'Red')
,(46,'20131217','19000101','20170310',2014,'Red')
,(46,'20110511','20120117','20110630',2014,'Orange');

declare @FinancialYear int = 2012;

select top 1 *
from @t
where FinancialYear = @FinancialYear
order by case when EndDate = '19000101'    -- Because you want 1900-01-01 to be seen as 'most recent',
                then '29990101'            -- you need to replace it with a value way into the future.
                else EndDate
                end desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, Dave! :)) Worked excellent however, when you select FY to be 2016 the output should show colour RED as EndDate string is empty, 1900-01-01 so no EndDate.  Does it make sense?

Comment: where FinancialYear < = @FinancialYear did the trick :) 
Thanks Dave! :)